# Try catch not working, Exception thrown at 0x00476F1E in game1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000004

Tags: c++, try-catch

Code:

```
try {
    SDL_SetColorKey(surfaces[folderCnt][surfacesCnt], SDL_TRUE, SDL_MapRGB(surfaces[folderCnt][surfacesCnt]->format, 255, 0, 255));
}
catch (int err) {

}
```

Error:
Exception thrown at 0x00476F1E in game1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000004.

When surfacesCnt = 10 it throws the error. That is because there is no surface 10. I know that and I want to catch the exception and process the next surface (surfacesCnt = 11).

Why are the try catch statements not catching the error? This would work perfectly in Python and Pascal.

Comment: That's an exception raised but the OS or CPU, or something else below C++. You can't catch with try/catch. Your program accessed a null pointer and crashed. Even if you do intercept and handle by installing a signal handler, odds are good your program is too broken to be safe to continue. Your best option is to test and handle ahead of time.

Comment: Okay. I know exactly what is causing the error and how to fix it. In fact it's intentional. I will be creating that missing surface but was just wondering why the try catch is not working.

Comment: I'm a bit frustrated at everything that is stripped away from C++ for the sake of performance compared to other programming languages. But at the same time it does not matter much because I can code around all that.

Comment: Why you are only catching specific exception of int type? why not generic exception catch?

Comment: Access violation should be avoided if you are aware of 10th index without data then at least handle that condition. May be you can default initiation of format.

Comment: @Seb0029 Unrecoverable errors exist in C++ not just for performance reasons, but because logic errors are inherently unrecoverable. They occur because of *programmer error* rather than user, input or external errors which indicates that there is a fundamental logic error in your code, thus your code cannot be trusted to continue even if it is to try to recover from that error.

Comment: @BuildSucceeded, because I'm following a C++ tutorial (https://www.w3schools.com/cpp/cpp_exceptions.asp). How can I catch generic exceptions? With catch (std::exception& e)? That also does not work and I get the same error.

Comment: Because signals are integers, I can see a case for catch by `int`, but then you'd also catch any other thrown `int`. If C++ was to do anything like replacing the current C-derived signal handling with try/catching signals, they'd add a signal type or, even more likely, derive from `std::exception`.

Comment: Does anyone know how other programming languages do manage to catch errors like the one I have here? For example, I can catch this same error in Free Pascal. Yet Pascal does not run in a VM.

Comment: @Seb0029 fix the access violation as it is impossible to catch in C++, the index handling where you dont have data as you mentioned at 10th Index. Can you should some code where you fill the surfaces variable. Exception handling help https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/exceptions

Comment: I can't help but wonder how stable the pascal program is after catching a segfault. In trivial cases you could pick up and carry on, but in the "WTF just happened cases?" who knows how much broke on the way to the visible manifestation.